# Is it possible to mock all fields of second level mocked object using mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I am using mockito framework in junit test class.

Here is the dependency graph of classes:

First is dependent on Second, Second is dependent on Third and Fourth.

I want to test First class. In my test class, I have mocked instance of Second. Now I want, for a mocked instance of Second class, all fields of Second class should also get mocked i.e. mocked instance of Second class should have mocked instance of Third and Fourth class (Second class has two fields Third and Fourth).

In the below test class, I want mocked instance of Second should have mocked instance of Third and Fourth in it.

```
public class FirstTest {

   @Mock
    private Second second;

    @Mock
    private Third third;

    @Mock
    private Fourth fourth;

    @InjectMocks
    private First first = new First();

    @BeforeClass
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        initMocks(this);
    }


    @Test
    public void testCallSecond() throws Exception {
        first.callSecond();
    }

}



public class First {

    @Autowired
    private Second second;

    public void callSecond() {
        second.call();
    }
}



public class Second {

    @Autowired 
    Third third;


    @Autowired 
    Fourth fourth;


    public void call() {

        System.out.println("third instance ======="+third);
        third.call();
    }


}
```

is it possible to mock all fields of second level mocked object? If yes then please suggest. I want to do it using Mockito framework only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are testing `First` and its interactions with `Second` by mocking `Second`. This means you are using a dummy version of `Second` that you can make return whatever you want when its methods are called.

`First` is unaware of the existence of `Third` and `Fourth` so there is no need to mock them at all.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 3):

You use the mocking framework to *remove transient dependencies*.

This means when testing `First` you mock `Second` and by doing so cut off all further dependencies.

in your test you verify that your code under test (cut) `Firlst` called the expected method on its dependency apllying the expected parameters and/or the output of your cut depending of the return value configured for the mock of `Second`

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)